# Problem closing a ssh tunnel in python 3 but not in python 2

Tags: pandas, postgresql, python-3.7

Good morning.

I'm trying to read a SQL query with pandas through a SSH tunnel. It worked fine in python 2.7, but now, with python 3.7, it seems like the process paused when trying to close the tunnel. My code is the following:

```
def conect(lista, names):

    # Block of code where I set used variables below.

    while not success and retries < max_retries:

        try:
            print('Trying to connect ({n})...'.format(n = retries + 1))
            sshtunnel.DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.DEBUG

            with SSHTunnelForwarder((REMOTE_SERVER, 22),
                                ssh_username = user_name,
                                ssh_pkey     = ssh_pkey,
                                ssh_private_key_password= password,
                                remote_bind_address=(str_number, PUERTO),
                                local_bind_address=('', PUERTO)) as tunnel:

                engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}".format(
                        user  = user_name,
                        passw = long_pass,
                        host  = tunnel.local_bind_host,
                        port  = tunnel.local_bind_port,
                        db    = db))

                conn     = engine.connect()
                dic_df   = {name: pd.DataFrame(conn.execute(query).fetchall(), columns = conn.execute(query).keys()) for (query, name) in zip(lista, names)}


            return dic_df

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error...')
            print(e)
        retries += 1
```

The logs I got with debug mode are:

> Python 2
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,563| WAR | MainThrea/0967@sshtunnel | Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,564| INF | MainThrea/0993@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from agent
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,564| INF | MainThrea/1042@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from host directory
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,674| DEB | MainThrea/1229@sshtunnel | Private key file (/Users/agarzon/Desktop/id_rsa, ) successfully loaded
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,675| INF | MainThrea/0914@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: **REMOTE SERVER**:22 as user **user_name**
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,675| DEB | MainThrea/0917@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,675| DEB | MainThrea/1355@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with key: 240aa5925ca5e09b3c905a48202bcfe2
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,690| WAR |  Thread-1/0368@ec        | /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
>     m.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,728| WAR |  Thread-1/0387@ec        | /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:96: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
>     self.curve, Q_S_bytes
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,730| WAR |  Thread-1/0368@ec        | /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:111: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
>     hm.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:02,825| INF |  Srv-5432/1389@sshtunnel | Opening tunnel: 0.0.0.0:**PUERTO** <> **str_number**:**PUERTO**
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:03,495| INF | MainThrea/1408@sshtunnel | Shutting down tunnel ('0.0.0.0', **PUERTO**)
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:03,588| INF |  Srv-5432/1395@sshtunnel | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:**PUERTO** <> **str_number**:**PUERTO** released
>
> 2019-04-03 16:12:03,597| DEB | MainThrea/1422@sshtunnel | Transport is closed

which works fine...

> Python 3
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,326| WAR | MainThrea/0967@sshtunnel | Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,327| INF | MainThrea/0993@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from agent
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,327| INF | MainThrea/1042@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from host directory
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,414| DEB | MainThrea/1229@sshtunnel | Private key file (/Users/agarzon/Desktop/id_rsa, ) successfully loaded
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,414| INF | MainThrea/0914@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: **REMOTE SERVER**:22 as user **user_name**
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,414| DEB | MainThrea/0917@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,415| DEB | MainThrea/1355@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with key: b'240aa5925ca5e09b3c905a48202bcfe2'
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,431| WAR |  Thread-1/0110@warnings  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
>     m.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,474| WAR |  Thread-1/0110@warnings  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:96: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for unsafe construction of public numbers from encoded data will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point
>     self.curve, Q_S_bytes
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,476| WAR |  Thread-1/0110@warnings  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py:111: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: encode_point has been deprecated on EllipticCurvePublicNumbers and will be removed in a future version. Please use EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes to obtain both compressed and uncompressed point encoding.
>     hm.add_string(self.Q_C.public_numbers().encode_point())
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:07,542| INF |  Srv-5432/1389@sshtunnel | Opening tunnel: 0.0.0.0:**PUERTO** <> **str_number**:**PUERTO**
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:08,184| INF | MainThrea/1408@sshtunnel | Shutting down tunnel ('0.0.0.0', **PUERTO**)
>
> 2019-04-03 16:16:08,229| INF |  Srv-5432/1395@sshtunnel | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:**PUERTO** <> **str_number**:**PUERTO** released

which is almost the same but, as you can checked, don't stop the connection with the tunnel. Also, if you break the code after setting the value of `dic_df` you can check that it's working fine equally, so I'm pretty sure that the fail coming from the stopping of the tunnel...

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe the engine is still connected and it's refusing to close the tunnel. Maybe try `with engine.connect() as conn:` or try closing `conn` explicitly. I don't use sqlalchemy, I use psycopg2 but I know that my connection block uses `with` just like the `SSHTunnelForwarder`. I've used a very similar setup to what you have here with Python3.6

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment here is an example of how I used psycopg2.

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder((SSH_HOST, 22),
                         ssh_username=SSH_USER,
                         ssh_password=SSH_PW,
                         remote_bind_address=('localhost', SSH_FOREIGN_PORT),
                         local_bind_address=('localhost', SSH_INTERNAL_PORT)
                         ) as server:

        with psycopg2.connect(host=server.local_bind_host,
                              port=server.local_bind_port,
                              dbname=DB_DATABASE,
                              user=DB_USER,
                              password=DB_PASSWORD
                              ) as conn:
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was a good point. I don't know why but I have had problems using psycopg2, so I have tried to adapt your solution to my code replacing `conn = engine.connect()` with `with engine.connect() as conn:`, but my problem persists ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have much more to offer. I just know while using Linux that if you have some process open related to your tunnel, it will hang until that connection is closed. For example, using an SSH tunnel to link a port to some foreign server. Then using another application like DBeaver that has an open connection to the foreign server, the DBeaver connection must be disconnected and then the tunnel will close.